# SQL Server - How to join with max value from second table and apply specific condition

Tags: sql-server, join, max

I have two tables:
Weeks

```
| WeekID | StartDate  |
|  1     | 2016-12-25 |
|  2     | 2017-01-01 |
|  3     | 2017-01-08 |
```

and Settings

```
| ID | SettingVal | ApplyFrom  |
|  1 | 10         | 2016-06-01 |
|  2 | 13         | 2017-01-01 |
|  3 | 5          | 2017-01-02 |
```

For each WeekID, I need to select SettingVal with MAX(ApplyFrom) existing, but also ApplyFrom <= DATEADD(day, 6, StartDate) from table Weeks, for example:

```
| WeekID | SettingVal |
|  1     | 10         |
|  2     | 5          |
|  3     | 5          |
```

When I write the following query:

```
SELECT t1.WeekID, t2.SettingVal
FROM Weeks t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Settings t2 ON t2.ApplyFrom <= DATEADD(day, 6, t1.StartDate)
```

it joins one row from first table with multiple rows from second table. How do I join only with a row having MAX(ApplyFrom), and select the SettingVal column I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1 - WITH TIES**

```
Select Top 1 with ties
       A.WeekID
      ,B.SettingVal
 From  Weeks A
 Left Join  Settings B
   on B.ApplyFrom<=DateAdd(DAY,6,A.StartDate)
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By A.WeekID Order by B.ApplyFrom Desc)
```

**Option 2 - Cross Apply**

```
Select A.WeekID
      ,B.SettingVal
 From  Weeks A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top 1 SettingVal 
                 From  Settings
                 Where ApplyFrom<=DateAdd(DAY,6,A.StartDate)
                 Order By ApplyFrom Desc
             ) B
```

**Both Return**

```
WeekID  SettingVal
1       10
2       5
3       5
```

Comment: Hello, My name is John;
 and I'm a Stackoverflow addict... no wait... that's me.

Comment: Thank you. That will help me. I wish I could be as good at SQL as you are. :D

Comment: @B.Sverediuk Thanks for the grin :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a query like this

```
SELECT 
t1.WeekID, 
t2.SettingVal
FROM Weeks t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
 SELECT 
  t3.WeekID, 
  MAX(t2.ApplyFrom) ApplyFrom
FROM Weeks t3
LEFT OUTER JOIN Settings t2 ON t2.ApplyFrom BETWEEN t3.StartDate AND DATEADD(day, 6, t3.StartDate)
GROUP BY t3.WeekID
)T4
ON T4.WeekID=T1.WeekID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Settings T2 ON T4.ApplyFrom=T2.ApplyFrom
```

Comment: Actually t2.ApplyFrom can be before t3.StartDate, like in my example, but still thanks for helping me.